# Is it possible to run windows 8.1 without monitor, keyboard or mouse?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, keyboard, mouse, macros

I have windows 8.1 and a macro recorder installed in my laptop. The macrorecorder executes some internet tasks automatically everyday in a schedule. I would like to transfer this automatization process to a fanless brick PC with windows 8.1 connected in a LAN, so I can turn it on with my laptop using WakeOnLan. But I really would like to avoid buying a monitor or a mouse or keyboard, since the macro recorder works fine without any of those connected. My question is... can windows 8.1 start(run) without any of those peripherals been connected? can windows 8.1 run without having a monitor connected? Without having any monitor connected, can it only be turned on only via VNC? any other workaroud? Is there somebody who knows a way to achieve something similar?

Thanks Advanced.
PD: I really will like to avoid having virtual keyboards displayed on windows 8.1 screen.

Comment: A Google search for `headless windows 8.1` suggests it may depend on your video card/drivers. You might want to edit that in

Comment: Hi @cde please could you provide some link or more info about it? Thanks Advanced.

Comment: Please someone, I need helpp!